# Storing password to logon to SQLPLUS from Shell scripts

Tags: shell, unix, passwords, sqlplus, aix

I have a number of Unix Shell scripts that logon to SQLPLUS in a batch environment. In order to logon to SQLPLUS the user and password are currently available to the shell script in plain text from a text file. Not Good ! I need to change this so that the password is protected and possibly encrypted, but the shell script can pick up the password and decrpyt to use. I'm not really sure how I would go about achieving my objectives, other than I presume I need to write some shell script code that can be in a library and pulled into all my shell scripts as required. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you want to hear.

Encrypting or otherwise obfuscating the password in your shell script does not provide any real security: only "security by obscurity" which isn't actually secure. This is a good reading about [passwords in plaintext](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Password).

So in my opinion it would be best, that as less people as possible have access to the shell script.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm aware that obfuscating the password is not real security, but in practice this all we are trying to achieve, as it will satisfy auditors. Also there is nothing to stop somebody changing code to grab the password when it is exposed, but as the only persons who will have access to the password are the code developers, who are the only persons with access to the scripts we can probably get away with restricted access and encrypt decrpyt.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO best possible solution in this case something like HashiCorp Vault [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/)
You are setting up Vault server in secure/audited network/host and store your password there (vault will encrypt it for you). Then you generating vault access token with rights to read db password. With Vault you have http(s) API which will give your secret if you have correct token (curl inside shell script). Examples: [api documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/index.html)

It is not best solution but with this you centralizing your secrets storage, everything encrypted, you can audit and revoke access to your secrets. This is way better than db passwords in plaintext all over your infrastructure.